# rounding numbers up in javascript having problems

Tags: javascript, math

hey i am having problems with rounding up numbers because Im not sure how i would go about doing it this is the code is use for the maths:

```
    var lon1 = position.coords.longitude* 0.0174532925;
    var lat1 = position.coords.latitude * 0.0174532925;
    var i = 0;

    while (i<locations.length)
    {
        x.innerHTML+= "<br>Distance " + calcDist(lon1, lat1, locations[i][1]* 0.0174532925, locations[i][2]* 0.0174532925);
        i++;
    }       
    }   
    function calcDist(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
    {
        return Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) + 
        Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2) *
        Math.cos(lon2-lon1)) * 3958;    
    }
```

the reason i am asking is because i am creating a store locator and this is for the distance between the two points the user and the store but when it works it out it shows as 5.595255493978103 instead of 5.6 miles

any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Round towards nearest multiple of 0.1
function round(x) {
    return Math.round(x * 10) / 10;
}
```

---

```
x.innerHTML+= "<br>Distance " + round(calcDist(lon1, lat1, locations[i][1]* 0.0174532925, locations[i][2]* 0.0174532925));
```

Comment: I'd probably use `Math.ceil`, but otherwise good answer.

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton I'm rounding towards the nearest number, though, as I assumed that was what he *really* wanted.  With `Math.ceil`, remember to adjust the `+ 0.5` to `- 0.5`, or just remove it if you want to round strictly up.

Comment: ...or just use `Math.round`. Derp. Forgot about that one.

Comment: this has worked perfectly thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Round towards nearest multiple of 0.1
 function round(num){
     return Math.round(num*10)/10;
 }

So...
round(3.14) = 3.1;
round(3.15) = 3.2;
```

Or for custom number of dps

```
function round (num,dp){
  var scale = Math.pow(10,dp);
  return Math.round(num*scale)/scale;
}

So...
round(3.456,2) = 2.46;
round(3.456,1) = 2.5;
roudn(3.456,0) = 2;
```

Comment: this has worked great thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can use Math.round() on values you intended to round!